# flutter initState() in showDialog()

Tags: flutter, dart

I have following function to show the popup with date selection, I need to show the default value in text filed while the popup show, but  when I enable the line  `dateinput.text =  DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd').format(DateTime.now());` the exception is happening. I have reade that it need to be inside `initState()` function.  But how can implement `initState()` here inside this function.

```dart
static datePickerPopup(
  BuildContext context,
  String title,
  Function(String framDate)? confirmation,
) {
  String framDate;

  TextEditingController dateinput = TextEditingController();
  //dateinput.text =  DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd').format(DateTime.now()); // this cause exception

  showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
      ),
      elevation: 0,
      title: Text(
        title,
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      ),
      content: StatefulBuilder(
          builder: (BuildContext context, StateSetter setState) {
        return Container(
          height: 90,
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Row(
                children: [
                  TextField(
                    controller:
                        dateinput, //editing controller of this TextField
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        icon: Icon(Icons.calendar_today),
                        labelText: "Start Date"),
                    readOnly:
                        true, //set it true, so that user will not able to edit text
                    onTap: () async {
                      DateTime? pickedDate = await showDatePicker(
                          context: context,
                          initialDate: DateTime.now(),
                          firstDate: DateTime(
                              2000), //DateTime.now() - not to allow to choose before today.
                          lastDate: DateTime(2101));

                      if (pickedDate != null) {
                        framDate =
                            DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd').format(pickedDate);
                        setState(() {
                          dateinput.text =
                              framDate; //set output date to TextField value.
                        });
                      }
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      }),
      actions: [
        TextButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.pop(context);
              if (confirmation != null) {
                //confirmation(_value);
              }
            },
            child: Text(
              'Send Program',
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.green),
            )),
        TextButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.pop(context);
            },
            child: Text(
              'Cancel',
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
            ))
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wait a frame to complete the build and then show dialog

```dart
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
      //show dialog
    });
  }
```

Also, if you like to wait specific time, you can use `Future.delayed`

```dart
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1)).then((value)  {

    //showDialog
  });
```

Comment: So where should I put  the code in above function.

Comment: Actually, you may just need to put `TextField` inside `Expanded` widget.